# Does Fidelity Have a Python Trading API?

Tags: programming, algorithmic-trading

I'd like to do my trading through a corporate account at Fidelity, but there does not seem to be a Python api.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

https://github.com/jmfernandes/robin_stocks

Answer (score 0):

Currently there does not seem to be an API. The only thing I could find is:

https://plaid.com/institutions/fidelity/

Comment: Plaid API has nothing to do with trading, it is for finding out how much money you have in your account(s), your past transactions, etc. It is a reporting or information tool.

Answer (score 0):

Fidelity has no API.  The only full fledged brokers with sufficient tools in the space are IBKRs and TDA (Now schwab).  However, Schwab hasn't released new API access requests and their entire API development seems stalled after the acquisition of TDA (formerly the TOS client).

However, as mentioned most brokerages have access to history and account information if that is something you're interested in.